# Auto-select fields in ms access hyperlinks

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vba

Hello I have a table in access with colums:

```
ID - Autonumber
Username - Text 
Display Name - Text
Auto - Hyperlink
```

I want to make the autofield like http://example.com/user=UsernameFieldHere and be able to click it in the datasheet view.

Also will be possible in the same time that I click on the hyperlink, to copy into the clipboard the Display Name field of that row?

Comment: VB.NET IsNot vba AndAlso IsNot access-vba

Comment: You can set it as a hyperlink field, I believe, and then build using the values from the other fields.  I don't have Access at work, so cant fully check.

Comment: Is `http://example.com/user=UsernameFieldHere` literally a website you want to go to? I just want to be clear that you don't want to go to another form in Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

1. Use a Calculated field in your table (instead of a hyperlink field). Set up the formula as `="http://example.com/user=" & Username` then on your form, when you bind that column to a text box set Format > Display as hyperlink = "Always".
2. Leave your table as is but in your form add another textbox and set the Control Source to `="http://example.com/user=" & Username` and same Display as Hyperlink setting as above.

Then, which ever of those you chose (though I favor the second), on the On Click event of your textbox you have

```
FollowHyperlink me.textBoxWithURL
ClipBoard_SetData UserName
```

That `ClipBoard_SetData` call is from the windows API. Microsoft provides all the example code for using the API. Just copy/past into a blank module and use `ClipBoard_SetData` as needed.

Comment: Thanks! But anyway to make it work just from the table? Without creating a form.

Comment: @aleeis No. But user's shouldn't be in a table directly any way. You can make your form be a datasheet so it *looks* identical to the table, though.

Comment: @aleeis To expand on my other comment, not only should you not do this in the table itself you actually can't by design. Tables can run some limited code though validation and through Data Macros but you cannot execute VBA. This is because you can connect to the underlying ACE/JET database but programs other than Access. So Access (the program which runs VBA) is not guaranteed to be running when data are changed in the table.